# Assistance with Simple Strings

Tags: python, string, oop, count, character

Complete beginner here.

Need some assistance on how to count the characters in EACH word of a string?

It seems simple enough, but clearly I'm missing something.

Thanks, SWMH

Comment: please provide more details.

Comment: Please post your actual question here directly. Have a doubt regarding how to ask a question? Check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AmitKumar let's say I input the text "Hello, good morning" I want Python to OUTPUT Hello = 5
Good = 4
Morning = 7

So giving count of the characters in each word

Comment: @SW96808 split the string by every spaces, then loop through each word, and simply call len.

Comment: `s="Hello, good morning"`
#split the string into list of words. remember to clean words (remove comma and other special char)
`s=s.split()`
#then loop through the list and print
`for word in s:
     print(word+' = '+str(len(word)))`

Comment: When you create a new question, please be more objective with the question title. A good question title is `How to discover the length of a string in Python?`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you can do something like this:

```
def return_length():
    
    words = input("Please input words\n")
    word_list = words.split(" ")  # Splits the sentence into list by spaces
    for words in word_list:  # loops over the list and prints the length
        print("String: \"{}\" is \"{}\" characters long".format(words, len(words)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    return_length()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `len` function.

```py
str = "Hello World"
str_length = len(str)
```